# Azure Active Directory - ID token can be translated into an authorization token (Access token)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, jwt, access-token, bearer-token

I am tasked with creating a service within Azure to translate a token coming from the internet as a logon and translate it to an access token so the users can access REST API's via an OAuth token - like a JWT.

I could use SSO for internal users and a 2 way authentication for external users and then I need to translate that to an JWT so I can authenticate my logic apps.

I can see that I could potentially use an Azure Function for this task and calling REST APIs to get the access token.

I would like to see how other people have done this because there seems to be many ways of doing it. Do I need to go the route of C#, MSAL and Azure functions or is there a low code option in getting it done quicker ?

Comment: This is referred to as a [JWT bearer grant](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7523) in OAuth terminology. I don't think Azure AD has support for this grant type natively. If at all possible, you should federate directly with the external OIDC IDP. Do you need MS Graph access tokens? If not, maybe look at some other identity brokerage options.

Answer (score 0):

> **Note** that: ID token cannot be translated to Access token in Azure Active Directory.

- Using the access token, a client application can use a particular resource to carry out particular tasks on behalf of the user. It is used for **authorization**.
- ID token proves that a user has been verified/authenticated.

Based on your requirement, you can generate access token either by scripting it or using REST APIs.

I generated **auth-code using below endpoint to authenticate** users:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize? 
client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code  
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query  
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345
```

Once the user signs-in the **code is successfully** generated like below:

[image]

I generated the **access token** using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
grant_type:authorization_code
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default openid offline_access
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

You can choose any authentication methods like *Client credentials*, *Implicit flow* or *authorization code*.

**References**:

[Acquire a token from the cache (MSAL.NET) - Microsoft Entra](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-acquire-token-silently)

[OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code Flow with Azure Functions and Microsoft Identity : Getting an Access Token by Brett McKenzie](https://brettmckenzie.net/posts/oauth-2-0-authorization-code-flow-with-azure-functions-and-microsoft-identity-part-1-getting-an-access-token/)